# Update notification

Tags: apt, updates, ppa, notification

I updated to version 16.04 of Ubuntu from version 15.10. 
I now get operating system update notifications from the Ubuntu Software program. But does not update other programs I have installed, IE Kcad, Geany. I have to use the software updater program to update these other programs, some of which require a PPA addition to software updater.

Is there a way I can get Ubuntu Software to look at these PPA sites for updates?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It sounds like the Y PPA Manager could help you by updating your PPAs.

Comment: when you update it automatically disables any added sources .. you need to go to Software & Updates and re-enable the sources. You may need to update the PPAs for the new OS version